# Filter Data from a specific Referer in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics on my web site.  I would like to see the traffic/counts of people coming from a specific domain.  How I can set this up in google analytics?  For example, my site is wwww.foo.com.  I would like to know how many people are landing on my site from www.bar.com (or get referred from www.bar.com).  Would be very helpful if someone was able to share steps to set this up in google analytics.

Thanks so much -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Standard Reports" section of your reports homepage, you can go to

Traffic Sources > Sources > Referrals

Then on the right, just above the metrics is a search field.  Just type in "www.bar.com" and click the spyglass icon.